# Electrical automotive pin

Tags: pins, pinout

[image]This pin came out of a 08 Honda Accord. I have been doing as much research as i can but to no avail haven’t been able to locate this type. The only markings on it are “B1”.Any info on to what type this pin is would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It measured 5.8mm wide and approximately 19mm in length

Comment: See if this looks right:  https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/2390259-1/21664106

Comment: They will have these at most auto-parts stores.  They often call them "quick-connect" terminals.

Comment: After looking at it closely that is not it unfortunately.

Comment: Every manufacturer's looks different.  The important thing is that it fits the tab it goes on.  If you know the tab width and thickness you can find a quick-connect terminal that will fit correctly.

Comment: That makes since. Since it was a pinout and not just a spade connector i was concerned about a direct match. Thank you

Comment: The [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) might be able to point you in the right direction.